# Firebase - Using Firestore's FieldValue

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a model, I have the following. However, upon upgrading to Version 9 of firebase, this no longer works.

> '"/node_modules/firebase/compat/index"' has no exported member 'firestore'.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

export interface ModelTest {
    date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue | firebase.firestore.Timestamp | Date;
}
```

I've had a quick browse through the documentation and haven't found a solution for this (yet..). Firebase has a 'compat' mode which is apparently temporary. To avoid implementing something temporary, is there a new way to import?

====

**UPDATE**

This seems to work:

```
import { Timestamp, FieldValue } from "firebase/firestore";

export interface ModelTest {
  date?: FieldValue | Timestamp | Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import the `compat` version of Firestore or any Firebase service that you are using as well if the core is imported from `compat`:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
// import 'firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]';
// compat version    ^^^
```

You can explicitly import `FieldValue` from non-compat version but it'll be best to use a single version for consistency.

Comment: Thanks Dharmaraj. I've just posted an update into my question. I found a segment in the documentation that highlighted FieldValue and Timestamp being imported independently. This appears to work.

Comment: You are importing them explicitly. It's like using both syntaxes....

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) seems to imply this is ok. The only place I'm using `compat` so far is in AngularFire. Given that AngularFire is currently using `compat` does that mean anytime version 9 of firebase is used (like the scenario above), then compat needs to be used there also? Given that firebase stated it's temporary, it doesn't 'feel' right to use compat if I don't need to. Are there negative effects in my update?

Comment: @Que what I meant to say was, if you need to use compat version just to use it along with AngularFire then just use that? Right now you are using modular structure just to initialize the Firebase SDK. I don't know if that's even having any benefit.

Comment: ahh I see what you mean. There won't be any benefit whilst using AngularFire until they update it (no tree shaking etc). I just have a new project with the new versions installed which feels better than a new project with the old versions installed and having to update it. There will be other uses for the Firebase SDK in the project.

Comment: I don't think so, if you'll be using AngularFire for most of the parts with compat SDK, it seems redundant to use the modular SDK just for initializing.